# Deployment : Deploy standard quick action which is creating member plan record

Tags: account, quickaction, create-records, deployment-error

We are trying to deploy a quick action(Add_Benefit_Plan ) which is present on Account Object. Action Type of this quick action is 'Create Record'. This quich action create the Record in Member Plan (Standard Object) object.  The relation between Account and Member plan is Master detail.

Account.Add_Benefit_Plan : You can’t change this field because MemberPlan has a master-detail relationship with Account.

Record_Page : omponent [force:highlightsPanel] attribute [actionNames]: We couldn't validate Quick Action Account.Add_Benefit_Plan.

Comment: sunil Bhoslae I saw a similar error "You can’t change this field because OutgoingEmail has a master-detail relationship with Contact." when deploying send email quick actions.  It turned out that I needed to enable email deliverability for all emails, and the error went away.

Answer (score 0):

Include in your deployment the master-detail field, even though it didn't change.

You can read the [background on this here from Gearset](https://docs.gearset.com/en/articles/2304486-master-detail-relationships), a vendor DevOps tool

Comment: cropredy, How does one do that, with standard object and standard fields?

Comment: @Tezyn - please post a new question, reference this question, and include in your question the exact metadata package you are attempting to deploy (stripping out all extraneous detail)

Comment: I'm trying to get clarity on your solution to the original poster's question.  If someone gets the "You can’t change this field because MemberPlan has a master-detail relationship with Account." error, when deploying a quick action for the Account, How can they include in their deployment "the master-detail field" for the MemberPlan to Account?

Comment: @Tezyn - I realize that but community convention would call for a new question - perhaps with a title that includes standard objects